# MongoDB journaling mechanics: what is the purpose of private view?

Tags: mongodb, memory, database-administration

I am going through a MongoDB online course. I have just watched the video ["Journaling's impact on resident memory"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TmmEzm50cw) that describes how MongoDB works with data in memory and how it's saved to disk. I have also read these articles on MongoDB journaling:

1. [Journaling mechanics](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/);
2. [How MongoDB’s Journaling Works](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/33700094220/how-mongodbs-journaling-works).

I cannot seem to grasp the justification behind the concept of private view.

[image: journaling diagram]

As far as I understand, when MMAPv1 is used as the storage engine and journaling is enabled, the following things happen to data in MongoDB:

1. When MongoDB starts, its existing data files are mapped into virtual memory using memory mapping (see [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap)). This area of the virtual memory is called **shared view**.
2. Shared view is then *remapped* into another portion of virtual memory called **private view**. Logically (not physically), it looks like all data is duplicated between the two views.
3. On a write operation, changes are applied to the private view.
4. Changes are also saved (incrementally) to a journal file.
5. When changes are confirmed to be stored in the journal, they are also applied to the shared view.

At some point after that, shared view will be flushed to data files on disk (this is called syncing).

At some point, shared view will also be remapped to private view.

## Question

Why is private view needed, at all? It looks like data in it is not used for anything that shared view can't be used for. Why aren't changes applied straight to the shared view before being written to the journal? This would make private view unnecessary and the footprint of MongoDB in the virtual memory would become half the size.

Comment: As a quick hint: The private view is connection-private, iirc. So when you make changes, you see them immediately, but they are only shared with other connections after they are persistent to disk, ensuring consistency.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Do you have any references that support this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [How Journaling Records Write Operations](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/#how-journaling-records-write-operations): "The private view stores data for use with read operations. The private view is the first place MongoDB applies new write operations. Upon a journal commit, MongoDB copies the changes made in the private view to the shared view, where they are then available for uploading to the database data files.  MongoDB next applies the journal’s write operations to the shared view. ..." As for the connection-private, I am actually not sure, but I think it was said in M202.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quote from the answer that William Cross has provided in MongoDB University forums.

> Imagine if there were only a shared view, and no private view. You
>   perform a write, and you want to first capture these writes in a
>   write-ahead log. You need the write-ahead log first because otherwise,
>   you would end up with your volatile memory evaporating on system
>   failure, with part of a write committed to disk and no way to roll it
>   back. The problem with a merged public/private view is that if you put
>   data in the public view, it could start getting flushed to disk at an
>   arbitrarily short interval, and this could happen before the journal
>   is done, if you're unlucky.
>
> If this happens, and the server goes down, then all you have is
>   corrupt data; there's no way to roll it back. Keep in mind, with
>   MMAPv1, most of the storage engine's work is pushed off onto the OS.
>   MMAPv1 was created to avoid the sort of fine-grained control over the
>   data going to disk that we would need here in order for the flow to be
>   what we want. So, in order to prevent this from happening, the public
>   view of the data stays the same until the write-ahead log entry is
>   completed on disk, and only then does the public view get updated. We
>   have the private view of the data so that it can exist in a totally
>   separate place, and get flushed to disk before we touch the public
>   view and risk having it partially committed to disk. In the mean time,
>   though, we've received a write, so we also have a private view to
>   answer requests for reads.
>
> In terms of exactly how it's written, I know that we write bytes, and
>   we start at the first change, so it's an offset + bytes. This keeps
>   things relatively minimal.

Answer (score 2):

In short, when you fire a write operation the mongod post the write opereation to private view first. Private view is a memory mapped file, after 200 ms it copies the data to journal which is child directory of your data/db.

And after a journal commit it copies the data to shared view which is flushed to data/db after 60s.

The reason is if there is database crush or dirty shutdown, it will still have the write operations in journal file. And once db comes up again it will replay all operations from journals to shared view and flush it back to main data/db.

Private view and shared view are allocated space in RAM. (Memory mapped file). To know more about memory mapped file. Say for example if your file is 2000 byte on disk then it will map it to memory address 10-10010, so you can read the file directly from memory address. Any change in file from memory address will be flushed back to file in your disk.